# How can I determine two numbers that are more close than others in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$arr = array (20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16);
```

I would like to get `5` and `7`. Because these are more close to each other than other items. In other word the difference between them is the lowest number:

```
7 - 5 = 2 // 2 is lowest number as the difference between all array's items
```

How can I do that?

---

```
$keep = $arr[0];
$diff = $arr[1] - $arr[0];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if ( ($keep - $item) < $diff && $keep != $item ) {
        $diff = $item;
    }
}
```

My code is incomplete, Because it just compares first item with other items.

Comment: by using 2 loop and one condition this may be achieve. should i try?

Comment: @FrayneKonok emm, no, lemme try it.

Comment: negative is allowed or always `abs` value???

Comment: This can easily be done using `sort()` and a `for` loop.

Comment: @FrayneKonok There are both negative and positive numbers. also there isn't any letter like `abc`. All items are digits.

Comment: @MarcoS OP does not have to accept any answer, just because he has to. He is free to accept, if any, the answer which helped him the most and solved his problem.

Comment: @stack Please don't write "thanks" comments under each answer. If you found any answer useful you can upvote it. But the comment is just considered noise.

Comment: @Rizier123 You are right .. but I like to say thanks to who help me out for free.

Comment: @Rizier123: of course OP is free to accept or not to accept a valid (and then useful) answer, but I suppose it's a good habit to accept one, since it can help future SO readers to more easily find the "best" solution to this question... Am I wrong?

Comment: @MarcoS The votes already show which answer was useful or not. The accept mark, a bit different, show which solved the problem and was the most useful one for the original poster.

Comment: @MarcoS So if you see some new user or a user who never accepted any answer you can write them a comment and explain how accepting works (e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234). But never force OP that he has to accep/upvote your or any other answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Explanation

So to get the two numbers in an array which are the closest to each other you have to compare each value with each other value. But you don't have to compare them with themselves and to the previous ones which you already compared.

To calculate how many comparisons you have to do you can use the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient):

> ```
> (n)            n!
> (k)   →   ─────────────
>           k! * (n - k)!
> ```

<sub>Where n is the total amount of elements and k how many you pick</sub>

And in your example this would mean:

> ```
> n = 6 //Array elements
> k = 2 //Two values which you compare
>
>      6!                  720
> ─────────────   →   ─────────────   = 15 comparison
> 2! * (6 - 2)!          2  *  24
> ```

Visualized

```
20 , 1 , 5 , 10 , 7 , 16  //Array values
↓    ↑   ↑   ↑    ↑   ↑
└────┴───┴───┴────┴───┘  //20 compared to all values, except itself
     ↓   ↑   ↑    ↑   ↑
     └───┴───┴────┴───┘  //1  compared to all values, except itself + [20]
         ↓   ↑    ↑   ↑
         └───┴────┴───┘  //5  compared to all values, except itself + [20, 1]
             ↓    ↑   ↑
             └────┴───┘  //10 compared to all values, except itself + [20, 1, 5]
                  ↓   ↑
                  └───┘  //7  compared to all values, except itself + [20, 1, 5, 10]

                         //16 compared to all values, except itself + [20, 1, 5, 10, 7]
```

Now to do this in code we need 2 loops to loop over the entire array for each value of the first loop. But as we already said we can ignore the value itself and the previous values, so for this we use 2 for loops and set the key, for the inner loop, to be the outer key + 1.

```
for($key = 0, $length = count($arr); $key < $length; $key++){          
    for($innerKey = $key + 1; $innerKey < $length; $innerKey++){
      //↑ Skipping the previous values and the value itself    
    }               
}
```

In the inner loop itself we just need to access the current value of the outer loop and get the difference compared to the value of the inner loop. That this also works with negative numbers we just wrap it into an `abs()` call to make the difference always positive.

Then we just check if the difference is smaller than the smallest difference which we already found, saved in `$nearest`. (We initialized `$nearest` by the difference of the biggest and smallest value of the array + 1):

```
if( ($diff = abs($arr[$keys[$key]] - $arr[$keys[$innerKey]])) < $nearest)
```

If the difference is smaller than the smallest difference which we already found, we write the two values into an array and set the new smallest difference:

```
$result = [$arr[$keys[$key]], $arr[$keys[$innerKey]]];
$nearest = $diff;
```

#### Code

```
<?php

    $arr = [20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16];

    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    $nearest = max($arr) - min($arr) + 1;
    $result = [];

    for($key = 0, $length = count($arr); $key < $length; $key++){

        for($innerKey = $key + 1; $innerKey < $length; $innerKey++){

            if( ($diff = abs($arr[$keys[$key]] - $arr[$keys[$innerKey]])) < $nearest){
                $result = [$arr[$keys[$key]], $arr[$keys[$innerKey]]];
                $nearest = $diff;

            }

        }

    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output

```
[5, 7]
```

Comment: As a note, [Merg Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) also can be a good approach to do that.

Answer (score 3):

> PHP `usort` is used here, as a note it is implemented with quicksort.

`$temp`  ==> Temporary array to store the two values and its differences while looping
             `$temp = [arr[$i] , arr[$j] , arr[$i]-arr[$j] ]`

```
   $arr = array (20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16);
   $temp=array();      
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr)-1; $i++)   
    {
        $diff=0;
        for ($j = $i+1; ($j < count($arr) && $i!=$j); $j++)
        {
            $diff=abs($arr[$i]-$arr[$j]);     //finding difference &taking absolute 
            $temp[] = array($arr[$i],$arr[$j], $diff); 
        }
    }
    usort($temp,function ($a, $b) { return $b[2] < $a[2]; });//sort `$temp[]` in ascending order according to the difference value
    list($x,$y,$d) = $temp[0];   //the first row of `$temp` contains values with the diff. is lowest 
                                //and the values is stored to `$x` & `$y` and there difference in `$d`
    echo "Related Values are $x and $y by $d";
```

Check results here http://ideone.com/pZ329m

**Working**

```
 20  1    5  10   7  16          //inner loop -----------------------                      
 |   |    |   |   |   |  $temp[]=[[20,1,19],[20,5,15],[20,10,10],...//$i=0 |// `20` is compared values from 1 onwards and the values and differences are stored in `$temp[]`
 |___|____|___|___|___|  //(eg., $temp=[20,1,|20-1|])        //$j=1,2,3,4,5↓
     |    |   |   |   |          [1,5,4],[1,10,9],...               //$i=1 | `1` is compared with values from 5 onwards
     |____|___|___|___|                                     //$j=2,3,4,5   ↓outer loop
          |   |   |   |          [5,10,5],[5,7,2],...               //$i=2 | `5` is compared with values from 10 onwards
          |___|___|___|                                     //$j=3,4,5     ↓
              |   |   |          [10,7,3],[10,16,6]                 //$i=3 | `10` is compared with values from 7 onwards
              |___|___|                                     //$j=4,5       ↓
                  |   |          [7,16,9]]                          //$i=4 |`7` is compared with final value `16`
                  |___|                                     //$j=5         ↓
```

> After getting `$temp[]` , it's sorted in ascending order according to the `differences` .
>   
> Then the first row of `$temp[]` gives our desired result .

**Whats inside `$temp[]`**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 6
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 9
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 9
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 10
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 11
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 13
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 15
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 15
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 19
        )

)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rizier123 , check my update and plz correct me if anythng is wrong

Answer (score 1):

As i comment to use 2 loop and a condition, i did the same thing. Just check it out and let me know.

```
$arr = array (20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16);

$c = count($arr);
$ld = max($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
    for($j = $i+1; $j < $c; $j++){
        $abs = abs($arr[$i]-$arr[$j]);
        if($abs < $ld)
            $ld = $abs;
    }
}
echo $ld; //2
```

if you need to know which two value has the difference then it is possible, just store them inside the if condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16);

$min = max($arr);
$closest = array();
foreach ($arr as $i) {
  foreach ($arr as $j) {
    if ($i != $j) {
      $diff = abs($i - $j);
      if ($min > $diff) {
        $min = $diff;
        $closest[0] = $i;
        $closest[1] = $j;
      }
    }
  }
}

print "The two closest numbers are " . $closest[0] . " and " . $closest[1];
```

Comment: this solution gives 7 and 16 as the closest numbers

Comment: You're right, coded in a hurry, sorry... Did already update answer with a working solution...

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I though such a simple code was quite explanatory, but you're generally right!

Answer (score 1):

Well, quick and dirty... two loops, one condition

```
//$arr = array (20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16); gives 5 and 7
$arr = array (-32,-15,4,6,-14,613,4,63,6,4);
$diff = INF;
foreach ($arr as $item0) {
    foreach ($arr as $item1) {
        $localdiff = abs($item0 - $item1);
        if ( $localdiff > 0 && $localdiff < $diff ) {
            $diff = $localdiff;
            $keep0 = $item0;
            $keep1 = $item1;
        }
    }
}

echo "Smallest distance was $diff, between $keep0 and $keep1";
```

Check it out on http://ideone.com/WdWOcb

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $arr = array (20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16);

$temp = array();
foreach ($arr as $item1) {
    foreach ($arr as $item2) {
        $aV = abs($item1-$item2);
        if(!in_array($aV, $temp) && $aV!=0)
            $temp[$item1."-".$item2] =$aV;
    }   

}
$closest = array_keys($temp,min($temp));
list($first,$explode,$second) = $closest[0];
print "The two closest numbers are " . $first . " and " . $second;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what happens in this situation:

```
$arr = array( 14, 20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16 );
```

In above case you have two couples with 2 as difference ( 7-5, 16-14 ). Following code returns all relative values.

We execute the standard two nested loops for comparing all elements (main loop excluding last element, nested loop starting from main index +1), then if the difference between current values is lower than previously retrieved difference, we replace it; otherwise, if the difference is equal to previous difference, we append a new couple:

```
$result = array( 'sum' => INF, 'values'=> array() );
for( $i=0; $i < count( $arr )-1; $i++ )
{
    for( $j = $i+1; $j < count( $arr ); $j++ )
    {
        $dif = abs( $arr[$i] - $arr[$j] );
        if( $dif < $result['sum'] )
        {
            $result = array( 'sum' => $dif, 'values'=> array( array( $arr[$i], $arr[$j] ) ) );
        }
        elseif( $dif == $result['sum'] )
        {
            $result['values'][] = array( $arr[$i], $arr[$j] );
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, for above array sample, you have this result:

```
Array
(
    [sum] => 2
    [values] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 14
                    [1] => 16
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 7
                )
        )
)
```

If you are interested in all value, simply you can find them in `$result['values']`. Otherwise, if you want (i.e.) min values (5 and 7), you can `usort`-it:

```
usort( $result['values'], function( $a, $b ) { return min($a)-min($b); } );
```

and use `$result['values'][0]`:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 7
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$arr = array (20, 1, 5, 10, 7, 16);
 arsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
 $arr = array_values( $arr ); 
 $min = 0;
 foreach( $arr as $index => $number ){
   if( isset($arr[$index+1]) ){
     $diff = abs( $number - $arr[$index+1] );
      if( $diff < $min || $min == 0 ){
      $min = $diff;
      $result = array( $number, $arr[$index+1] );
     }
   }     
 }
 print_r( $result );
```