# How can I conglomerate an array of forecast data in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, design-patterns, similarity

### The Setup

I have an array of rain probability that I'm outputting as a forecast:

```
$rain_probability = array(
  '7am'  => '33',
  '8am'  => '0',
  '9am'  => '8',
  '10am' => '7',
  '11am' => '8',
  '12pm' => '19',
  '1pm'  => '8',
  '2pm'  => '13',
  '3pm'  => '50',
  '4pm'  => '50',
  '5pm'  => '60',
  '6pm'  => '60',
  '7pm'  => '7',
  '8pm'  => '5',
  '9pm'  => '0'
);

$forecast = 'The likelihood of rain is: ';

foreach( $rain_probability as $hour => $percentage )
{
  $forecast .= "$hour: $percentage%. \n";
}

echo $forecast;
```

### The Results

> The likelihood of rain is:
>   7am 33%.
>   8am 0%.
>   9am 8%.
>   10am 7%.
>   11am 8%.
>   12pm 19%.
>   1pm 8%.
>   2pm 13%.
>   3pm 50%.
>   4pm 50%.
>   5pm 60%.
>   6pm 60%.
>   7pm 7%.
>   8pm 5%.
>   9pm 0%.

### Desired Results

I'd like this to be more human-friendly, like this:

> The likelihood of rain is:
>   7am: 33%.
>   8am-11am: less than 10%.
>   12pm: 19%.
>   1pm: 8%.
>   2pm: 13%.
>   3pm-4pm: 50%.
>   5pm-6pm: 60%.
>   7pm-9pm: less than 10%.

### What I Tried

Thought this would be pretty simple, so I began writing a loop that would check to see if the probability for the previous hour was the same as the current hour. Then needed to special case for numbers less than 10%. Then had to special case the first and last array elements. Pretty soon I was in the midst of a lot of conditional statements and (excuse the pun) the code was not very dry anymore. And wasn't sure there wouldn't be bugs with certain combinations or sequences of probabilities, and could setup tests for that. But overall started feeling like I may be reinventing the wheel and that maybe there was a better approach.

### The Question

My question is not "how can I make this work" - but rather does there exist a classical approach, pattern, or even a class or library for solving this problem?  ( Sort of feels like a computer science homework assignment )

Comment: maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047193/how-can-i-determine-two-numbers-that-are-more-close-than-others-in-an-array you could make use of `abs` to sort of check those elements are close, then you could merge them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem too convoluted, just needs a little love...

Input:

```
$rain_probability = array(
  '7am'  => '33',
  '8am'  => '0',
  '9am'  => '8',
  '10am' => '7',
  '11am' => '8',
  '12pm' => '19',
  '1pm'  => '8',
  '2pm'  => '13',
  '3pm'  => '50',
  '4pm'  => '50',
  '5pm'  => '60',
  '6pm'  => '60',
  '7pm'  => '7',
  '8pm'  => '5',
  '9pm'  => '0'
);
```

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3097d697bf82d30faa1e92e4841822c2e19a2105)):

```
array_walk($rain_probability,function(&$v){$v=($v<10)?'Less than 10%.':"$v%.";}); // prep %

$forecast="The likelihood of rain is:\n";
$start=$end=$perc='';
foreach($rain_probability as $hour=>$percent){
    if($perc==$percent){                               // merge forecast line
        $end="-{$hour}";
        $perc=$percent;
    }else{                                             // start new forecast line
        if($start){$forecast.="$start$end: $perc\n";}  // skip on first iteration
        $start=$hour;
        $end='';
        $perc=$percent;
    }
}
$forecast.="$start$end: $perc";                        // add final forecast line
echo $forecast;
```

Output:

```
The likelihood of rain is:
7am: 33%.
8am-11am: Less than 10%.
12pm: 19%.
1pm: Less than 10%.
2pm: 13%.
3pm-4pm: 50%.
5pm-6pm: 60%.
7pm-9pm: Less than 10%.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml
If i understand it right you need `k-means`